# PostgreSQL TRIGGER on WITH (UPDATE ..)UPDATE on 2 tables

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, with-statement, postgresql-triggers

I have an SQL query like this:

```
    WITH whatever1 AS (
        UPDATE
            table1
        SET
            field1 = <some number>
        WHERE
            id = <id>
        RETURNING id, field1
    )
    UPDATE
        table2
    SET
        field2 = (whatever1.field1 * 100000000::BIGINT)::BIGINT
    FROM
        whatever1
    WHERE
        field3 = whatever1.id
    RETURNING
        field3 AS whatever2
```

and I have this trigger that does not let me do the `UPDATE` above:

```
CREATE FUNCTION public.function1()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$function$
BEGIN

    IF NEW.field1 != OLD.field1 THEN

        IF (NEW.field1 * 100000000::BIGINT)::BIGINT != (SELECT "field2" FROM table2 WHERE NEW.id = field3) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Help me with this trigger so this exception is not raised.';
        END IF;

    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON public.table1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE function1();
```

Note the comparison part should be ok, because
`select 428872 = (0.00428872 * 100000000::BIGINT)::BIGINT` returns `true`.

I guess the problem is with the chained `UPDATE`s not updating both tables at once.
Replacing `BEFORE` with `AFTER` helps, but I don't understand all implications...

I actually read about `CONSTRAINT TRIGGER`, `DEFERRABLE`, `INITIALLY DEFERRED` and `REFERENCING` and I still understand nothing, but most if not all of them use `AFTER` TRIGGER, not `BEFORE`, it's even hard to test all possible combinations.

How to update the trigger so the top-most SQL query passes?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) "*The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, **the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable***"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I would guess it, but what that means for me? I actually have the trigger in both ways, that's not a problem.

Comment: Could you add the table contents before the statement that triggers the error and the statement itself?